# How do I force a background picture to always be centered on the screen despite the screen resolution?

Tags: html, css, image, web

Is it possible to have the center of my background picture always be in the center of the screen, and have the sides be cropped off to compensate for resolution? I'm currently using background-image: cover to crops the sides without regard for the middle, but I want what's in the center of my picture to always be in the center of the page. Mostly I want to do this so that mobile looks good, but doing this would also help make it more device-compatible.

What it looks like on [desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw320.jpg)

And what it looks like on [mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDyIb.png). (disregard the tint from CF Lumen)

I want the girl to be in the center of the screen on all devices.

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried?

Comment: I've tried what Vicky has posted and I've tried different settings of background-size and background-position. Not sure what else to try, first time using CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css property `background-position: center;`

> Also to fit the background in all screen sizes,  you ll have to
>   maintain image's size by `background-size:100% 100%;` or whatever best
>   suits you. And to stop repeating the background use `background-repeat:no-repeat`

The above settings would differ the display of the image device to device i.e. in some devices the image can look very streched.
So Media Query would be an ideal solution.

Comment: This works, but when the screen isn't as high as the image it loops it. I just want it to cut the parts that aren't visible off. CSS noob, but thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it's still not exactly what i'm looking for. What it's showing on smaller devices right now is the full image in the center and just whitespace on the top and bottom, like so: https://i.imgur.com/KF0UWRa.png

What I'm looking for exactly is the girl to be in the middle of the page and the rest surrounded by the snow in the image. I can post code if it'd help.

Comment: you can change the height of the image by altering: `background-size:100% 100%;` but it will look streched in some devices..

Comment: Hmm, it does looked stretched, I see what you mean. I want the height to be 100%, but the width to expand outwards beyond the screen as necessary. Is there an option for that?

Comment: `background-size:auto 100%;` would do that :)

Comment: Actually, I realized I could remedy this problem by making a media query and if it's a phone I can do background-size: auto 100%, and if it's a desktop I can do background-size: 100% auto. Let me try that, I appreciate your help a ton.

Comment: Worked! Mostly. I'm just gonna hope people with weird resolutions don't visit this site. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap , then you can just apply CSS class "img-responsive" to the background image.